# Poor runtime of O(n^2) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, time-complexity

I am trying to solve [SPOJ Beads](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BEADS/) with Haskell but I'm exceeding the time limit. I am <strike>pretty sure</strike> my algorithm complexity is the best I can get. Therefore I am suspicious that Haskell itself is the problem (library, strictness etc.), but I have no clue what it could be.

```
import           Data.Array
import           Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- readLn
    interact $ unlines . fmap proccess . take x . lines

proccess :: String -> String
proccess line = show $ minimumDisjoint line

minimumDisjoint :: String -> Int
minimumDisjoint s = minimumBy sortFn [1..len] -- gets minimum elem from list O(n)
    where
    len = length s
    str = listArray (1, len) s
    sortFn i1 i2 = foo i1 i2  -- basically 'string1 > string2' O(n)
        where
        foo i3 i4
            | i3 > len      = foo 1 i4
            | i4 > len      = foo i3 1
            | i3 == i1 -1   = ord
            | ord == EQ     = foo (i3+1) (i4+1)
            | otherwise     = ord
            where
            ord = compare (str ! i3) (str ! i4)
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: As the input is only ASCII, you should try using `ByteString` everywhere instead of `String` to get O(1) indexing instead of O(n) in `sortFn` and much faster I/O.

Comment: I am not familiar with Haskel, but what is the approach you are using, maybe u can briefly explain it ? The problem can be solved in `O(n)` and `O(n*log(n))` time and both should easily pass the test.

Comment: This looks like at least `O(n^2)` as there's `O(n)` indexing inside the `O(n)` `minimumBy` callback, likely worse as the callback is calling itself.

Comment: Ye, it is O(n^2) if you count in the string comparing algorithm.

Comment: @FordO. If it is `O(n^2)` then the problem is the algorithm, not the language

Comment: @Dogbert Oh I didn't know that bytestring has O(1) indexing, I was considering to use text, which has **inefficient** index according to docs, so I used listArray + String instead. Problem is that if I use ByteString, I will have to use `B.pack . show` and I am afraid that it will slow down my algorithm too much.

Comment: @Yerken Are you sure? The sortFn is basically `string1 > string2`.

Comment: Pretty sure `O(n^2)` for a string of length `1e5` is already an order of `1e10` operations which is roughly a few seconds even in the best optimised `C` code on a powerful machine.

Comment: @Yerken Wow, in that case the solution is a bit more tricky than I thought. Thanks, I will try to find better algorithm.

Comment: @FordO. where would you have to use `B.pack . show`? You can use the I/O functions in the `ByteString` module.

Comment: Normally if you see a time limit of 0.5s, such as this problem you need to strive for a solution which is either linear or `O(n*log(n))`, if you want I can provide you with the approach, but then again it would be off-topic given the original topic is asking for troubleshooting haskell code :P

Comment: @Dogbert If I want to use `interact $ unlines . fmap ..` I need to be able to create [ByteString]. Do you have any solution, that doesn't use `interact` but keeps the elegancy?

Comment: @FordO. There's `ByteString.interact`, `ByteString.Char8.unlines` and `ByteString.Char8.lines`.

Comment: @Dogbert Ye, but the function I pass to fmap must be `fn :: ByteString -> ByteString`, which means I will need to call `pack . show` (check how is the `proccess` function written).

Comment: @FordO. ah, you can make `proccess :: ByteString -> String`. The only place you'll use `String` then is when converting the `Int` to a `String`, which should be fast enough as it's only going to be called once per line. The main performance killer here is the O(n) indexing in `compare` which will become O(1) with `ByteString`.

Comment: @FordO. also, from the comment, it looks like you can just use `compare` on `String` or `ByteString`? Does that give a different result?

Comment: @Dogbert No I cant, that was just simplification for people who dont understand Haskell. Is the built in method that much faster than my function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120581/discussion-between-ford-o-and-dogbert).

Answer (score 0):

Your worst case is string with all elements equal, looks like `minimumDisjoin` is *O(n^2)*.

Perhaps this would work, and may be *O(n)*:

One pass over string to find list of indices of the minimal element.

But rather than a list you want start position and length of consecutive runs of indices : run length encoded

Handling wrap around goes next.

Then take position(s) after the longest length run(s).

Next pass needs to compare points after set of longest run only.  Worst case is this is half size of original list, and is comparing nonoverlapping strings, much more efficient than original overlapping problem.

Comment: much simpler - take the string x, and attach it to itself, x -> x + x. Now build the suffix array and among them pick the minimum suffix with starting index from range [0..n-1]